# Perl- Making a "Do While" exit when the input is an integer number or empty

Tags: loops, perl, do-while

I have this "Do While" loop and I want to exit it when the user's input is an integer number or empty but I am having some troubles implementing this behavior.

```
do {
   $input = <STDIN>;
} while ($input != "" && $input !~ /^\d+$/ );
```

Is there any way to interrupt the loop manually like for example

```
if($input == " "){
   break;
}
```

Comment: To start, you use `eq` and `ne`, not `==` and `!=` when comparing strings in perl.

Comment: Also, use `chomp` or take the trailing `\n` into account.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword for breaking out of a loop in Perl is [`last`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last), but that doesn't work for the `do { ... } while` construct because [`do` is not a loop block](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do).

Your code is almost correct. You need to [`chomp` your `$input`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp) to remove trailing newlines, and it will work.

Comment: what about `!=` vs `ne` and possible lack of `use strict; use warnings;` that reminds that...

Comment: @Neither those have already been pointed out in comments. Warnings are not on, or they'd have noticed the wrong comparison operator. `$input` cannot have a `my` in that example because it would be lexical inside the block, and then the `while` condition wouldn't be able to access it. But I agree they should have `strict` and `warnings`.

Comment: `chomp` has been too

Comment: @Neither yeah, while I wrote my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

The underlying problem is that the input isn't an empty string when someone presses just enter; it's a line feed. Using `chomp` will remove that line feed.

```perl
my $input;
do {
   chomp( $input = <> );
} while $input ne "" && $input !~ /^\d+\z/;
```

Note the use of `ne` to compare strings. Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!

---

One could also use

```perl
my $input;
do {
   chomp( $input = <> );
} while $input !~ /^\d*\z/;
```

---

But let's answer the explicitly-asked question.

Perl has the (IMHO better-named) [`last`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last) operator. (See also: [`next`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/next), [`redo`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/redo))

Unfortunately, `do BLOCK while EXPR` is a special case of the `EXPR while EXPR;` statement modifier, and `last` doesn't affect loops created by statement modifiers.

To use `last`, the loop could be reworked into an infinite loop.

```perl
my $input;
while (1) {
   chomp( $input = <> );
   last if $input =~ /^\d*\z/;
}
```